# Why does Azure Cache use more that 30% memory?

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I'm running an Azure Cloud Service that uses the "new Azure Cache".

I've configured the Cloud Service to use 30% of memory (default), but still the CacheService keeps eating the memory to a point where the server starts to swap out memory to disk. The server has 3.5 GB RAM (Medium), and the CacheServices used 2GB after running for 3 days (and keeps growing). Se attached picture.

We don't even use the cache, so this makes me rather nervous.

Another weird thing is that the other server in the same deployment does not have this problem.

Can anyone tell me if this is normal, should I be worried, or is there a setting somewhere, that I'm missing?

[image]